# How to restrict UIGestureRecognizer to a particular UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I have a set of UIViews that are layered like this:

- UIWindow
- UIViewController
- UIView (covers entire Window; tag:41)
- UIView (tag: 100 (covers the top half of UIView (tag:41))
- UIScrollView (in lower half; tag:126)
- UIView (covers UIScrollView; tag:21)
- UIView (tag:22)  <----- covers a portion of the tag-21 UIView

The top UIView (tag:22) is the only UIView that I want taps to be recognized for. Using NSLog, the tag always refers to tag:41.

Here is my code in the ViewController (**-viewDidLoad** method):

```
    // Create and initialize a tap gesture  
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTap:)];
 tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
 tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

This is the code that handles the tap (also placed in VC)

```
- (void)singleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {

CGPoint pt = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

UIView *v = [self.view hitTest:pt withEvent:nil];
NSLog(@"\n\nx: %ld\ny: %ld\ntag: %d",(long)pt.x, (long)pt.y, self.view.tag);

if ([v isKindOfClass:[SubViewData class]]) {
    NSLog(@"SubViewData!");
    return;
}
```

}

Reading the Event Handling Guide (page 32)  I see that the 1st view that falls within the constraints of the tapped area is the one that gets the hit-test, which in this case would be tag:41.  I need tag:22 to get the hit test, because there is another UIView (tag:100) sitting on the top half of tag:41 which also recognizes the tap...

**UPDATED:**  I added the code to handle the taps... is there a way that I can programmatically reject the taps unless it's for UIVIew tag:22?

Comment: To which view did you add the gesture recognizer?

Comment: Added to viewController for tag:41... tag:22 didn't have it's own VC... (I guess I should have mentioned there is a VC between the UIWindow and UIView with tag:41)

Comment: Why arent you adding the gesturerecognizer to the view in question directly?

Comment: Not recognized... put it in -viewDidLoad... nothing happens!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try attach it to whole view, implement delegate method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
   return (CGRectContainsPoint(self.myTargetView.frame, [sender locationInView:self.view]);
}
```

if you have several `UIGestureRecognizers` and you delegate for each, use:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (self.neededGestureRecognizer == sender) {
       return (CGRectContainsPoint(self.myTargetView.frame, [sender locationInView:self.view]);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

to match'em

Comment: What do you mean by "whole view"?  and what do you mean by "implement delegate method"?  (sorry for the lame questions, but have never used UIGestureRecognizer before)

Comment: I mean your UIViewController's view.

Comment: iFreeman:  I updated the question with the code I have now... it's still reporting tag:41... is there a way I can programmatically reject the tap for tag:41 and let it go up the chain?

Comment: Did you try to attach UIGestureRecognizer directly to UIView with tag 22? I mean [my22TaggedView addGestureRecognizer:myRecognizer]; ?

Comment: and maybe you should try update your current code with [recognizer locationInView:self.scrollView] if your 22 tagged view is a subview of UIScrollView

Comment: iFreeman... haven't forgotten about you...just got hung up on another issue... will try this tomorrow... thank you for your patience. :D

Comment: iFreeman: I finally got it working... had to mess with the gesture recognizers and check if the tap was within bounds.  thank you for your time and patience.